# Finding offset for code segment in x86 assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm a newbie at x86 assembly programming and I've come across this problem during one of my assignments. 
My aim is to write Interrupt Descriptor Table entries for certain interrupts (say INT 32 or INT 35, both being user defined interrupts). I looked at the Intel x86 Developers Manual and I've found the structure of the IDT entries. For the purpose of this question, lets consider my program to have the following structure:

```
myCodeGeneratingInterrutpt35:
  ...
  ...
  ...

someOtherCode:
  ..
  ..
  ..

myInterruptHandlerForInterrupt35:
  .
  .
  .
  IRET

someOtherInterruptHandlers:
 ... ..
```

This code lies in the code segment starting at address, say 0xa1000 (which is stored in CS). Let the IDTR be pointing to some address, say 0xe5000. And I have 8-byte entries corresponding to each of the IDT entries starting at [IDTR]. So by my calculations, the entry for INT 35 is at 0xe5118. 
(a).   Could you guys give me a way to find out the address of the code starting with "myInterruptHandlerForInterrupt35: ... "? 
(b).   Also, how do I find the offset of the code "myInterruptHandlerForInterrupt35" from CS ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in protected mode, you should know your `CS` for the kernel. Even if you don't, you must already be in kernel mode to be able to modify the IDT, so assuming you only have a single code segment, the current `CS` is going to be `CS` for the interrupt handler. Note that `CS` by itself has nothing to do with the base address, since that is stored in the GDT or LDT as applicable. As such `starting at address 0xa1000 (which is stored in CS)` only makes sense if you meant that a selector for a segment starting at that address is in `CS`.

As for the offset, that's of course just the address of the label.

Comment: Hey Jester! Thanks for the answer. Could you also tell me how to find the address of the label ? Any mathematical formula or insight into this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you want ... just use the label name and the assembler and linker will take care of the rest.

Comment: The problem I have is in defining the IDT entry for INT 35. The IDT entry requires the Segment selector for the interrupt handler, and the offset from the code segment where the interrupt handler routine is located. I am facing a problem in calculating the offset for 'myInterruptHandlerForInterrupt35' when my code segment starts from 'myCodeGeneratingInterrupt35'

Comment: `CS` is your selector, and the label is your offset. What's the problem?

Comment: What is the numerical value that I put in the offset field when I define my IDT entry?

Comment: Who cares? Use the label!

Comment: Umm. I think I might have not stated my question properly. My IDT entries are going to be defined as specified in _Intel_x86_SDM : Vol 3, Ch. 6, Section 6.11. The offset I speak of, in my question, is the offset specified by 'Offset 31:16' 'Offset 15:0' bits in the table. I'm not sure how I can just use the label in there.

Comment: That depends on your assembler. To get 15:0 you might just have to do `dw label` or similar. To get 31:16 you might have to do `dw label >> 16`. Certain assemblers are not clever enough to do this at compile time, for that case you will have to fill it in at runtime using the same logic.